# “Re” prefix vs remote

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, prefixes

My first post here, hello everyone. :)
Feel free to suggest changes to this question.

I was just wondering why is the word remote unlike the other words starting with “re” like replay, reply, relocate, remove where the “re” is the prefix meaning again. Is there any historical reason behind this?

Are there other words like this? :)

Edit: Actually, I'm referring to my TV remote here, I do know remote also = far..

Comment: According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remote), _remote_ comes from the past participle form of the Latin _removere_ (to remove), which I found amusing since _remove_ is listed as one of your examples.

Comment: Worth pointing out that English takes words from a number of different languages, so there are plenty of words starting with "re" which have nothing to do with that prefix. For example, "ream", "reap". And there are even words with etymologically latin roots that start with "re" and have nothing to do with the prefix; e.g. "regal", ["real"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/realis#Latin).

Comment: The "again" _re_- prefix goes on action verbs and it means to perform the action again. _Remote_ is borrowed from Latin, and the _mote_ part is the  past participle of the verb _removeō, removēre, remōvī, remōtus_ 'remove' (i.e, move again). So _removed_ can also have the 'distant' sense, though _remote_ is more likely; and there are idioms like _at some remove from, a position removed from the battle,_ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the explanation.

> **re-** a prefix, occurring originally in loanwords from Latin, used with
>   the meaning “again” or “again and again” to indicate repetition, or
>   with the meaning “back” or “backward” to indicate withdrawal or
>   backward motion: regenerate; refurbish; retype; retrace; revert.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/re-)

"remote" means (or meant) "moved back from".

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, I referred to my TV remote and not remote=far.

Comment: Yes, a TV remote allows you to move back from (far from) the TV and still control it.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Well, your T.V. remote gets its name from the other definition of remote. The full name for that device is a "remote control" because it controls a device (in this case, a TV) remotely.